# ASP.NET MVC Paste to clipboard

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, clipboard

I have a ASP.NET MVC 4 app.

I want to copy a text(from PDF) CTRL+C and paste it as parameter in a method from a controller.

My webgrid has column with an ActionLink

```
grid.Column(" ", " ", format: @<a href="@Url.Action("Clipboard", "People", new { cbdata = window.clipboardData.getData('Text') })">Clipboard</a>),
```

...

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Clipboard(string cbdata) // is string ok ?
    {
        //I'm doing something with my clipboard data ..
        return View();
    }
```

This part is not working : *window.clipboardData.getData('Text')*
Do I have to modify my MapRoute in Global.asax.cs ?

**Q** : How can I get the data from my clipboard in a method from my controller ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You want to get data from a client's clipboard to the web server?

You can't. Security is an issue. What if someone had their credit card details saved in their clipboard from a previous copy!

The only way to do that is to ask the user to explicitly paste it into a text control and send it in a form..

Comment: The PDF could have 2-3 pages. What control shoud I use, ASP.NET or jQuerry control ? I would prefer ASP, I'm not that good at JS/jQuerry.

Comment: Not sure... maybe you can send the doc as an attachment and use pdf text extraction on the server. That's only a suggestion really.

Comment: save the pdf as a binary in my database ?