# Clipboard.GetImage() returns null in MVC

Tags: c#, model-view-controller, window

I have an MVC application where i am running windows' SnippingTool.exe to take the screenshots. Clipboard.GetImage() returns null when i am trying to get the captured image to save at a particular location.

```
[STAThread]
    public ActionResult AddImages(UserEntry model)
    {

        if (!Environment.Is64BitProcess)
            System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("C:\\Windows\\sysnative\\SnippingTool.exe");
        else
            System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("C:\\Windows\\system32\\SnippingTool.exe");


        IDataObject obj = Clipboard.GetDataObject(); //returns null
        Image img1 = Clipboard.GetImage();  // returns null

        return View();
    }
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ASP.NET MVC Paste to clipboard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10699983/asp-net-mvc-paste-to-clipboard)

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that you start `SnippingTool` and instant right after that you try to get data from the `Clipboard`. Since `Clipboard.GetImage()` is executed right after just the start of `SnippingTool`, you haven't been able to assign an image to the `Clipboard` in time. (because you just got a few milliseconds to do so)

So just access the `Clipboard` after you are 100% sure that you just stored your desired image in it. Do it e.g. in a button click event:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    IDataObject obj = Clipboard.GetDataObject();
    Image img1 = Clipboard.GetImage();

    //now do with the image whatever you want, you may want to store it as a public field thought to
    //access the image in your whole application
}
```

---

Or you can monitor the `Clipboard` with some p/invoke. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/621582/8283469) is a guide how to get notified once the value of the `Clipboard` has changed. Basically you set a viewer to the `Clipboard`, so you recieve a WindowsMessage about a value being assigned to the `Clipboard` which can be intercept in the `WndProc()` function by overriding it and adding a check for this specific mentioned WindowsMessage.

Comment: For how long shall i wait to access the image after capturing the image? Because when i try to paste image in paint it works fine.

Comment: @RoshanJha You have to capture the image **and** store it in the `Clipboard`. After that you can instant access your `Clipboard` and will get the image.

Comment: so basically you are saying after capturing the image i have to set the Clipboard image after that only i can retrieve it?

Comment: @RoshanJha If I understood your english correct, then yes. `1.`Make a screenshot with SnippingTool. `2.`Get this screenshot any way you want into the Clipboard. It's your decision how you give the image to the Clipboard. `3.`Since you send the image to the Clipboard you can access the image through the Clipboard. I don't know if you understood yet, but the Clipboard is the temporary storage for *Copy and Paste*. So `Ctrl + C`. The SnippingTool does not, according to my knowledge, auto pastes the screenshot to the Clipboard. That's what you have to do, to be able to access it later again.

Comment: @RoshanJha If it doesn't work please let me know. If it works though, feel free to accept my answer as the accepted answer. :)

Comment: @RoshanJha What about any reaction? Please tell me if you understood my solution and if it works for you.

Comment: Hey, Thank for concern. That didn't work out. It was running perfect on my `visual studio` but when hosted on `IIS`, `SnippingTool` was not firing up. I went with some workaround solution in the end. And i don't know if this makes any difference or not but I am working on an `MVC` application not `Web Forms` or `Window Application`.